# How can I catch the Exceptions from a method when I call a method in pyqt5 when pushing a button

Tags: python, exception, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I catch the Exception from a method when I calling it in "clicked.connect".What I did was:

```
    try:
        self.parameter_search.clicked.connect(self.search.filter)
    except Exception as e :
        self.error_msg.setText(str(e))
        self.error_msg.exec_()

 def filter(self):
    if self.path is None:
        raise Exception("No file was choosen")
    if self.Enter.text()=="":
        raise Exception("No parameter was enterd")
    value=self.Enter.text()
    data=self.read_file(self.path)
    choosen_parameter=self.parameter.currentText()
    if choosen_parameter=="Choose a Paramter":
        raise Exception("No Parameter was choosen")
    if value.isdigit():
        data=data[data[choosen_parameter]==str(float(value)).replace('.',',')]
    else:
        data=data[data[choosen_parameter]==str(value)]        
    if data.empty:
        raise Exception("This Value isn't existed please try again!")
    value=self.correct(value)
    data.to_csv(self.dir+choosen_parameter+"="+value+".csv", index=False,sep=";")
    self.prog_msg.exec_()
```

when I did it nothing happened what should I do to get to catch the Exception

Answer (score 2):

It cannot, it should be understood that the connection only indicates to the Qt eventloop that when the signal is emitted then some callable will be invoked and nothing else.

If you want to handle an exception then an intermediate function:

```
    self.parameter_search.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

def on_clicked(self):
    try:
        self.search.filter()
    except Exception as e :
        self.error_msg.setText(str(e))
        self.error_msg.exec_()
```